# jQuery $('#form').submit() versus javascript document.form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Can anyone please explain why this line of code will submit my form:

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

But this line will not?:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Everything else is exactly the same, but switching out that single line in my javascript makes a huge difference.  I do NOT have any input elements with a name of 'submit', in case any of you are wondering.

Edit:  Both the id and name of my form element here are "myForm"

Comment: First one uses the form's `name`, the second tries to use the `id`, and will fail if there's no such `id`.

Comment: `document.myForm.submit()` won't trigger the submit handlers attached to the form but `$('#myForm').submit();` will

Comment: As the other comments imply, we'd like to see some HTML.

Comment: out of curiosity, jquery included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a conflict with jQuery's validation plugin.  Someone else in my project added this plugin to the page, and so I didn't realize that the $('#myForm').submit() version was triggering that validation and preventing form submission.

I appreciate the help from everyone who responded!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

Refers to

```
<form name="myForm">
```

---

but

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Refers to

```
<form id="myForm">
```

---

So use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('form[name="myForm"]').submit();
```

Comment: Up-voting because you make a great point (and said it well), but this isn't the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`document.myForm.submit();` is referencing the `name` attribute of the `form` which must be `myForm` since it's working.

The jQuery snippet `$('#myForm').submit();` is looking for a form with the ID `myForm`, not looking by name, so if your form does not have the `id` attribute set to `myForm` that's why you are seeing this behavior.  Obviously the latter line of code also requires jQuery included on the page to work since it's not vanilla JS.

Comment: That *may* be the reason for the behavior. We don't know for certain because OP didn't provide enough code to give an accurate answer.

Comment: @BlueSkies correct, it could be plenty of other things, but I am assuming this based on the minimal info given and the perceived skill level of the person asking the question. I guess maybe it should be a comment instead pending further clarification from them?

Comment: You know what they say about assuming. It makes an a** out of you and me... ;)

Comment: Up-voting because you make a great point, but this isn't the answer to my problem.